# Sending Multiple SMS Messages in Twilio Reply

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am writing software using the Twilio API, Flask, and Python to send and receive SMS messages. When I reply to a message, I also want to send out a message to a different phone number (thereby sending 2 messages in total, one to the original sender, and one to an entirely different individual).

I reply to an SMS using:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reply():

    # Send other text
    sendMessage(to_number, text)

    # Send response      
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.sms(response)
    return str(resp)
```

Where the `sendMessage` function is:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient 

def sendMessage(to_number, text): 

    ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXX" 
    AUTH_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXX" 
    twilioNumber = "XXXXXXXXX"

    client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN) 

    client.messages.create(
        to=to_number, 
        from_=twilioNumber, 
        body=text,  
    )
```

But the `sendMessage` function does not actually send a text to the separate number (note the reply still works). Note also that the `sendMessage`function works fine when it is called outside of the reply function.

How should I go about sending two different texts to two different numbers in response to a text from only one of those numbers?

Comment: Where does the `to_number` parameter come from?

Comment: The `to_number` parameter is coming from a SQL database, but I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I couldn't see where `to_number` was being defined and if it was undefined then that would be a good indication of why it wasn't sending messages. Perhaps the `to_number` is not being returned correctly during your controller action and that is why you can't send messages from the route, but it works when you call it by hand.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me to send the same message to multiple numbers:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient 

def sendMessage(text):
    ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXX" 
    AUTH_TOKEN = "YYYYYYYYYY"
    twilioNumber = "+15551235554"
    client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

    NUMBERS = {
        'Foo':'+15551235555',
        'Bar':'+15551235556'
    }

    for name, number in NUMBERS.items():
        message = client.messages.create(
            to=number, 
            from_=twilioNumber, 
            body=text)
        print message.sid
```

Maybe you can find a way to adapt this to your specific needs. Note that Twilio limits your outbound SMS to 1 SMS message segment per-second, per-number. [More info on Rate-Limits](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-are-the-limits-on-outbound-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second)

Comment: they have now removed the "TwilioRestClient" instead we can use 
from twilio.rest import Client
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple responses to a user reply by calling the `MessagingResponse()` method. I used a list to store multiple messages and then I looped over the list to send each message as it is shown below.

```
def incoming_message() -> str:
    '''
    Receive incoming messages
    '''
    # Get the message the user sent our Twilio number
    incoming_message = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    # Get the phone number of the person sending the text message
    phone_number = request.values.get('From', None).replace('whatsapp:', '')
    if validate_phone_number(phone_number):

        # Get the message the user sent our Twilio number
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        # Determine the right reply for this message
        # msg = resp.message()
        # Query the database for the phone number
        if incoming_message:
            # deconcatenate the list of messages and send them as different messages
            for message in conversations(phone_number, incoming_message):
                msg = resp.message(message)

        else:
            pass
    else:
        msg.body("Lo sentimos, no se encuentra registrado en nuestro sistema. Por favor comuniquese con nosotros para poder ayudarlo.")

    return str(resp)

def conversations(phone_number: str, incoming_message: str) -> list:
    '''
    Conversations with the user
    '''
    messages = list()
    client = Client.query.filter_by(phone=phone_number).first()

    if incoming_message:
        match incoming_message:
            case 'hola':
                messages = [
                    f'¡Hola {client.name}! Gracias por hacer tu reservación con nosotros ', 'cómo podemos ayudarte?']

            case 'adios':
                messages.append(
                    f'¡Adios {client.name}! Esperamos verte pronto ')
            case 'menu':
                messages.append(
                    f'¡Hola {client.name}! Estos son los servicios que ofrecemos: \n 1. Ubicacion \n 2. Reservacion \n 3. Cancelar reservacion \n 4. Salir')
            case _:
                messages.append(
                    f'No pude entender tu respuesta  Inténtalo nuevamente  o escribe menu para desplegar las opciones con las que podemos apoyarte.')

        # return the list of messages in different messages

        return messages

    else:
        pass
```